# how to overwrite vuetify.js style

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have v-textarea element which by default has border bottom:

```
.v-text-field > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot:before {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin 0 0 0
```

I want to overwrite that class to not have that border but it doesn't work. Here is how looks my code:

```
  .v-text-field>>>.v-input__control>>>.v-input__slot:before{
      border-style: none !important;
  }
```

Comment: What are the [`>>>` operators](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) meant to do in this context? Try using `>` instead

Comment: I tried with > but it also doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Vue you can use scoped styles to make sure a style only applies to current component. This allows you to use [deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors).

```
<style scoped>
.v-textarea >>> .v-input__slot:before {
  border-style: none;
}
</style>
```

You can also use the usual css parent/child selector `>` without scoped styles.

```
<style>
.v-textarea > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot:before {
  border-style: none;
}
</style>
```

Another way to not affect all `v-textareas` globally is to use a custom class.

```
<v-textarea class="my-textarea"></v-textarea>
<style>
.my-textarea > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot:before {
  border-style: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I have bee using scoped style. I removed now .v-input__control>>> like you mentioned and it works now well! thank you!